# A future heartbleed bug?

Tags: tls

Checking out IBM.com and Google.com:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ibm.com&s=172.230.109.66

Valid from  Tue Sep 09 14:00:34 UTC 2014

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=google.com&s=74.125.239.36

Valid from  Wed Sep 10 13:31:45 UTC 2014

It's very uncommon that two very big corporations re-generates their cert in almost the same time.

**Q:** Could this be a sign of a vulnerability in SSL that they shared between each other?

Comment: No. If they were both *revoking* certs, you could make a case that this might be a possibility.  Issuing new certs tells you nothing.

Comment: The cert is only valid for 2 months, I'm guessing this cert is regenerated every 2 months.

Comment: I've been noticing a bunch of certificate updates on Google, Twitter and other websites too. In all cases it changed, if I remember correctly, the MD5 fingerprint to undefined or something. Seems to be related to the recent discussion about accepted hashing methods for certificates in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

In digital time, a full day apart does not seem like "almost the same time". As mentioned in the comments, this would also be done every two months, likely at a regular interval. IBM and Google aren't the only very big corporations, add in Amazon, Microsoft, Apple, etc. and chances are there will be some that land even closer than 1 day apart. Not to mention that there is nothing unusual about a regeneration. An analogy might be similar to "Bill Gates and Jeff Bezos both filled their car up with gas this weekend (1 day apart, add in timestamps), could there be some future terrorist plot involving gas?" note that even if the time was exactly the same, it has nothing to do with a standard behavior or the security aspect of it.